# Retrieve posts between two dates

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have posts which contain the following ACF custom fields: a startdate and an enddate in this format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

I want to retrieve all posts with a startdate less than 24 hours ago and an enddate less than 24 hours ahead using the `WP_Query`.

How do I do this?

Comment: I cannot see your code  or am I blind?

Comment: Use a [meta_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in your WP_Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet,

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'surf_reports',
  'posts_per_page' => '1',
  'date_query' => array(
   array(
       'after' => '24 hours ago'
       )
  )
);
```

(https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194352/only-display-post-if-published-in-last-24-hours)

OR

```
 // Run the query.
 $expire_window = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('1 day'));
 $expiring_ads = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type'      => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'     => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'start_date',
                                    'value' => $expire_window,
                                    'compare' => '<='
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'end_date',
                                    'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                                    'compare' => '>=',
                                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                                )
        )
    ));
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a meta_query - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query.

Simple Example:

```
$start = '2011-11-31';
$end = '2011-10-01';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-event-type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => '_my-datetime-from',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_my-datetime-from',
            'value' => array( $start, $end ),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);
// Make the query
```